# Identifying substrings based on complex rules

Tags: regex, r, string-matching

Assume I have text strings that look something like this:

```
A-B-C-I1-I2-D-E-F-I1-I3-D-D-D-D-I1-I1-I2-I1-I1-I3-I3
```

Here I want to identify sequences of markers (`A` is a marker, `I3` is a marker etc.) that ***leads up*** to a subsequence consisting ***only*** of `IX` markers (i.e. `I1`, `I2`, or `I3`) that contains an `I3`. This subsequence can have a length of 1 (i.e. be a single `I3` marker) or it can be of unlimited length, but always needs to contain at least 1 `I3` marker, and can only contain `IX` markers. In the subsequence that leads up to the `IX` subsequence, `I1` and `I2` can be included, but never `I3`.

In the string above I need to identify:

```
A-B-C-I1-I2-D-E-F
```

which leads up to the `I1-I3` subsequence which contains `I3`

and

```
D-D-D-D
```

which leads up to the `I1-I1-I2-I1-I1-I3-I3` subsequence that contains at least 1 `I3`.

Here are a few additional examples:

```
A-B-I3-C-I3
```

from this string we should identify `A-B` because it is followed by a subsequence of 1 that contains `I3`, and also `C`, because it is followed by a subsequence of 1 that contains `I3`.

and:

```
I3-A-I3
```

here `A` should be identified because it is followed by a subsequence of 1 which contains `I3`. The first `I3` itself will not be identified, because we are only interested in subsequences that are followed by a subsequence of `IX` markers that contains `I3`.

How can I write a generic function/regex that accomplishes this task?

Comment: 1. For sequence A-B-I3-C-I3 what should be the answer? ["A B", "C"] or something else?

Comment: 2. For sequence I3-A-I3 what should be the answer?

Answer (score 4):

Use `strsplit`

```
> x <- "A-B-C-I1-I2-D-E-F-I1-I3-D-D-D-D-I1-I1-I2-I1-I1-I3-I3"
> strsplit(x, "(?:-?I\\d+)*-?\\bI3-?(?:I\\d+-?)*")
[[1]]
[1] "A-B-C-I1-I2-D-E-F" "D-D-D-D"

> strsplit("A-B-I3-C-I3", "(?:-?I\\d+)*-?\\bI3\\b-?(?:I\\d+-?)*")
[[1]]
[1] "A-B" "C"
```

or

```
> strsplit("A-B-I3-C-I3", "(?:-?I\\d+)*-?\\bI3\\b-?(?:I3-?)*")
[[1]]
[1] "A-B" "C"
```

Comment: think this is what op expected.. not?

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the sequences which contains `I3` with following regex :

```
(?:I\\d-?)*I3(?:-?I\\d)*
```

So you can split your text with this regex to get the desire result.

See demo https://regex101.com/r/bJ3iA3/4

Comment: I think \d should be \\d, and I still can't get it to work in R: `invalid regular expression '(?:(?:I\d-?)*(?<=I3)(?:-?I\d)*)', reason 'Invalid regexp'`

Comment: @JakubP. Yep, there is no need to use look behind. and thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following expression: `(.*?)(?:I[0-9]-)*I3(?:-I[0-9])*`.
See the match groups:
https://regex101.com/r/yA6aV9/1