# Matching regexes

Tags: regex, r

I have this code:

```
library(stringr)
library(devtools)

full_patterns <- source_gist("446417161352179ce42c")$value
literal_strings <- source_gist("21f5cf342e20c6e4a1e8")$value
literal_strings <- literal_strings[order(nchar(literal_strings), decreasing = TRUE)]

regex_list <- list()
for (i in 1:length(literal_strings)){
  regex_list[i] <- paste0("(?<=", literal_strings[i], "?)(?:I\\d-?)*I3(?:-?I\\d)*")
}

IVs_identified <- list()
DVs_identified <- list()

for (i in 1:length(regex_list)){
  DVs_identified[[i]] <- lapply(full_patterns, str_extract_all, regex_list[[i]])
  IVs_identified[[i]] <- lapply(full_patterns, str_extract_all, literal_strings[[i]])
}

data.frame(unlist(DVs_identified), unlist(IVs_identified))

length(unlist(DVs_identified))
length(unlist(IVs_identified))
```

The point of the code is to generate a data.frame with two columns. The first column should contain the first part of the regex match (contained in `literal_strings`). The second column should have the second part of the regex match (i.e. `(?:I\\d-?)*I3(?:-?I\\d)*`, but ***only if*** it is preceded by the appropriate literal string). The second part of the regex matches the specifications described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449589/identifying-substrings-based-on-complex-rules). In short: it is an uninterrupted sequence of markers (i.e. `I1`, `I2`, and `I3`) that only contains `IX` markers, and where `I3` at least occurs once. In other words, markers such as `FA` does not occur inside of this sequence.

To make this work the line `literal_strings <- literal_strings[order(nchar(literal_strings), decreasing = TRUE)]` is crucial. This orders the literal strings so that the longer strings come first. This is because the intention is that once a section of `full_patterns` is matched, it should be ignored. For example, the longest literal_string is `IFA-NR-TR-TR-FA,TR-NR-FA-NR-NR-QU-QU-NR-IFA-EX-TR-NR-FA-QU-I2-EX-II2-NR-TR-TR-I2-EX-NR-QU-EX-I2,QU-TR-NR-QU-NR-FA-TR-QU-EX-II2-I2-I2-I2-II2-FA-EX-TR-TR-QU-NR-NR-NR-TR-I2-FA-QU-ITR-EX-FA,TR-I2-NR-QU-FA-IFA-TR-EX-NR-FA-NR-FA-EX-FA-FA-QU-NR-NR-NR-INR-TR` and one of the shortest is `FA`. However, at this point (towards the end of the process) we are not interested in matching the single `FA` markers that were already matched inside of previous literal_strings.

As you can see, the code doesn't work because the two lists that are generated are of different lengths - they need to be of the exact same length. How can I accomplish this?

**For debugging** (since running this on R 3.1.2 does not seem to work):
My `sessionInfo()` gives:

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringr_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5  tools_3.2.0   stringi_0.4-1
```

Comment: *should* they be the same length? are `DVs_identified` and `IVs_identified` correct after the loop?

Comment: @rawr: yes, they should be the same length, because they are defined in terms of each other - we are only interested in matches where part 1 is followed by part 2.

Comment: Does this code work? When I tried, I had to wrap your regex in a perl(function) to get it to use perl regex syntax and even then it's complaining about your lookbehind assertion not being fixed length because of the ? mark at the end...

Comment: @gymbrall: It works for me (except for the `data.frame` call that crashes because the lengths are not the same.

Comment: The code gives an error for me - invalid regular expression (and that's after adding the necessary `library(stringr)` call at the top).

Comment: @Dason: you are right about `library(stringr)`, however I don't understand what is different across our configurations - I just ran the script in a fresh R session and it works for me...What else could be causing this discrepancy?

Comment: What version of R / stringr are you using?

Comment: @Dason: `sessionInfo()` pasted in question. It seems I also have `stringi` loaded which may make a difference...

Comment: I'm on 3.1.2 which might be part of the issue.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error in the latest version of R for Windows (I just did a fresh install)

Comment: So, is the problem because you expect your condition to be true in each case (it is followed by the appropriate literal string)  or because you expect the times it does not match for the regex to create an empty string match that would result in the lengths of the arrays being the same

Comment: @gymbrall: The latter of your alternatives is better as it retains more information - it would tell me where there are no matches. Further - the literal string comes first, then the regex.

Comment: I don't think the question is clear enough to be able to help you. As of right now "FA-" appears 64 or 65 times in the raw data and matches as many times based on the literal string. However, with the regex, you require that any instance of "FA-" be followed either immediately by  "I3" or "I" and some number and then "I3" which is not going to be anywhere near the 65 times that "FA-" was found by itself. In other words, unless I'm missing something, I have no reason to believe these two lists should match in length and no reason/direction to modify the regex in any way to achieve that.

Comment: @gymbrall: I have updated the question, and hopefully it is now more clear. Any feedback will be appreciated. If a literal string is found and it is not immediately followed by the second part of the regex, then the first column should list the literal string and the second column should just return empty, i.e. `""`.

Comment: Sorting the literal_strings doesn't achieve anything except to order the result set. Each pass of `DVs_identified[[i]] <- lapply(full_patterns, str_extract_all, regex_list[[i]])` is with one specific literal_string. So, it doesn't matter where "FA-" appears in the list, it's going to get called against the full string until every instance of it is found.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
library(stringr)
library(devtools)
library(Hmisc)


full_patterns <- c("I2-EX-I3-EX-I2-IEX-I3-I2-EX-I2-I2-II3-I2-III2-I2-I3-INR-FA-NR-I3-INR-IEX-QU-I3-NR-FA-EX-QU-NR-I2-I2-I2-NR-TR-II2-I3-NR-IIEX")
#full_patterns <- c("I2-EX-I3-EX-I2-IEX-I3-I2-EX-I2-I2-II3-I2-III2-I2-I3-INR-FA-NR-I3-INR-IEX-QU-I3-NR-FA-EX-QU-NR-I2-I2-I2-NR-TR-II2-I3-NR-IIEX-NR-NR-INR-NR-I3-I2-NR-IQU-QU-ITR-QU-NR-NR-QU-TR-NR-ITR-IFA-II2-QU-TR-FA-EX-QU-QU-QU-NR-QU-ITR-FA-QU-FA-FA-TR-FA-QU-EX-QU-IQU-QU-FA-FA-QU-QU-FA-FA-I3-NR-FA-II2-FA-QU-FA-I2-FA-NR-INR-TR-NR-EX-NR-NR-EX-TR-I3-INR-NR-FA-ITR-EX-NR-NR-IINR-INR-EX-EX-EX-NR-NR-NR-FA-FA", "FA-I2-I2-I2-EX-I2-I3-FA-II2-TR-II2-FA-I3-IFA-FA-NR-I3-I2-TR-II2-II2-FA-I2-II3-FA-QU-II2-I2-I2-NR-I2-I2-NR-II2-INR-I3-QU-I2-I3-QU-NR-I2-INR-QU-QU-I2-IEX", "FA-FA-ITR-IIFA,TR-FA-I2-I2-FA-EX-IFA,IEX,I2-I2-INR-I2-I3-I1,TR-NR-I2-I3-EX-IQU-TR-I3-NR-EX-I3-EX,I2-EX-IIIII2-II3-I2-EX,FA-IEX-EX-TR-EX-TR-I3-INR-I2-FA-FA-TR-I2-IIIIIFA-I2-FA-TR-III3-NR-FA-III3-TR-I2-I2,I2-I2-EX,TR-TR-I2-FA-I2-I3-IIIFA-ITR-FA-IFA-INR-NR-II2-I3-I2-FA-II2-EX-FA,I3-I3-TR-I3-FA-NR-II2-II3-TR-TR-EX,I3-TR-NR-TR-QU-EX-NR-TR-I2-EX-III3-INR-INR-IFA,TR-I3-I2-I3-NR-NR-I1,IIFA-FA-IFA-FA-NR-II3-NR-I2-FA-FA-IFA-NR-FA,IFA-FA-NR-NR-I2-NR-IIIFA-EX,II2-II2-I2-QU-TR-FA-QU-I3-EX-ITR-IFA-FA-NR-INR-FA-FA-EX-II2-NR-I3,I3-FA-I2-I2-FA-I2-FA-I2,I2-INR-I2-NR-II3-TR-FA-I2-I3,I3-NR-EX-TR-IEX,II2-FA-I2-INR-I2-I3-IIEX-FA,IEX-EX-EX-EX-EX-EX-EX-TR-TR-I2-NR-NR-EX-NR-I3-FA-NR-NR-NR-EX-NR-II2-IIFA-FA-ITR-NR-I2-I3-I2-NR-FA-NR-I1")
literal_strings <- c("I2")
#literal_strings <- c("FA-QU-II2-I2-I2-NR-I2-I2-NR-II2-INR-", "QU-I2-", "QU-NR-I2-INR-QU-QU-I2-IEX-", "FA-", "QU-EX-NR-", "NR-EX-", "NR-EX-TR-", "QU-")
#full_patterns <- source_gist("446417161352179ce42c")$value
#literal_strings <- source_gist("21f5cf342e20c6e4a1e8")$value
escaped_literals <- lapply(literal_strings, escapeRegex)

regex_list <- list()
for (i in 1:length(literal_strings)){
  regex_list[i] <- paste0("(?:(?=", escapeRegex(literal_strings[i]), ")(?:I\\d-?)*I3(?:-?I\\d)*|(?=", escapeRegex(literal_strings[i]), "))")
}

IVs_identified <- list()
DVs_identified <- list()

for (i in 1:length(regex_list)){
  DVs_identified[[i]] <- lapply(full_patterns, str_extract_all, regex_list[[i]])
  IVs_identified[[i]] <- lapply(full_patterns, str_extract_all, escaped_literals[[i]])
}

unlistDVs <- unlist(DVs_identified)
unlistIVs <- unlist(IVs_identified)

for(i in 1:length(unlistDVs))
{
  print(unlistDVs[i])
  flush.console()
}

print("---------------------")

for(i in 1:length(unlistIVs))
{
  print(unlistIVs[i])
  flush.console()
}



data.frame(unlist(DVs_identified), unlist(IVs_identified))

print(length(unlist(DVs_identified)))
print(length(unlist(IVs_identified)))
```

I've stripped the data down in the sample above to identify what (I believe) is causing the discrepancies. The reason why this is not working should become obvious. In the small sample set I've set up, the sixth I2 gets matched, but because of the way it correctly matches the regex `I2-I2-I3`, It skips over a literal_string match (there are two `I2`'s in one legal regex match). Obviously, this is just an example, but I think it's pretty easy to see that occurring in other cases.

I think the way I've structured the regexes is correct, the issue is that the optional part of the regex you've provided `(?:I\\d-?)*I3(?:-?I\\d)*` can sometime match multiple literal_string matches which causes a discrepancy. I've spent more time on this than is probably reasonable, so unless there is something I'm missing, I'm probably going to bow out.

Comment: Can you try this with `full_patterns <- source_gist("446417161352179ce42c")$value; literal_strings <- source_gist("21f5cf342e20c6e4a1e8")$value`...it doesn't seem to work for me. It seems to be generating `regex_list` in the wrong way - not all entries get filled.

Comment: I've run a number of different tests and I've updated my answer. Let me know what you think.